# How to use component on forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, shared, xamarin.forms

I got a component from Xamarin's component store and It's available to Android and iOS...

How can I use this component on shared/portable project (forms)?
Or can I join a forms content with a ViewController? I can't understand this :X
I see something called "wrapper" but I don't remember where and I can't find it anymore!

This is my code:

1 -I create an interface in the shared/PCL project

```
namespace UsingDependencyService
{
    public interface IActionTray
    {
        void ActoinTrayBiulder ();
    }
}
```

2 - I implement the interface

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof(ActionTray_iOS))]
namespace UsingDependencyService.iOS
{
    public class ActionTray_iOS : IActionTray
    {

        UIActionTray leftTray = new UIActionTray (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        public ActionTray_iOS ()
        {
        }

        public void ActoinTrayBiulder ()
        {
            leftTray.trayType = UIActionTrayType.Draggable;
            leftTray.orientation = UIActionTrayOrientation.Left;
            leftTray.tabLocation = UIActionTrayTabLocation.BottomOrRight;
            leftTray.frameType = UIActionTrayFrameType.EdgeOnly;
            leftTray.tabType = UIActionTrayTabType.IconAndTitle;

            // Style tray
            leftTray.appearance.background = UIColor.LightGray;
            leftTray.appearance.frame = UIColor.DarkGray;
            //leftTray.icon=UIActionImage.FromFile ("Images/icon_calendar.png");
            leftTray.title = "Tab";
            leftTray.CloseTray (false);
        }
    }
}
```

3 - I tried to use it from the shared/PCL project:

```
    public class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {

            DependencyService.Get<IActionTray> ().ActoinTrayBiulder ();

        }
    }
}
```

It's called...but it don't appear on my view.
How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is Xamarin's DependencyService (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/)

You should add the component to your platform-specific project, and then you create the interfaces for accessing them from your Forms project.

Here's some code to explain the process.

First, create an interface in the shared/PCL project

```
public interface IActionPackAlert
{
    void ShowAlert(string title, string text);
}
```

We're just gonna do iOS in this example. So in your iOS project you should implement the interface

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (ActionPackAlert_iOS))]
public class ActionPackAlert_iOS : IActionPackAlert
{
    public void ShowAlert(string title, string text)
    {
        UIActionAlert.ShowAlert (title, text);
    }
}
```

Great. We're done with the platform specific implementation. Now let's try to use it from the shared/PCL project:

```
DependencyService.Get<IActionPackAlert>().ShowAlert("Hello from Xamarin Forms", "This was called platform-specifically from the shared project");
```

Comment: The component the I got from Xamarin's store is a "native component"?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you're still in doubt what to do, tell me what component you are using, and I'll try to be more specific

Comment: Yeah... I tried to do it.
I'm using the item ActionTray from ActionPack component... Wait.. I'll try a thing

Comment: It wasn't work...

I follow that guid... I try it on shared project:



`public interface IActionTray : ContentView`
`{`
`void ActoinTrayBiulder ();`
`}`

and I get the message:
`Xamarin.Forms.ContentView' in interface list is not an interface.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice ActionTray. I only saw ActionPack. ActionTray probably needs to be done in your separate native projects only. I don't think it can be done in the shared/PCL project

Comment: I can do something like call a view using conditionals?
Like: 
On SharedProject{
#if android:
call a UIViewController from android project
#if IOS
call a UIViewController from iOS StoryBoard;
}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem resides in the frame/bounds you are setting for the UIActionTray, and when those bounds are set by the OS?

For what it's worth though, I was able to use the ActionTray with Xamarin.Forms (PCL) using some custom renderers.  Here is an example iOS custom renderer for the ActionTray:

In the Xamarin.Forms PCL project, you'll want a minimum of the following:

```
public class ActionTrayView : View
{
    public static BindableProperty TrayTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create((ActionTrayView v) => v.TrayType, ActionTrayType.Draggable);
    public ActionTrayType TrayType
    {
        get 
        {
            return (ActionTrayType)GetValue(TrayTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TrayTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static BindableProperty OrientationProperty = BindableProperty.Create((ActionTrayView v) => v.Orientation, ActionTrayOrientation.Bottom);
    public ActionTrayOrientation Orientation
    {
        get
        {
            return (ActionTrayOrientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OrientationProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public enum ActionTrayType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When the user taps the ActionTray's DragTab, the tray will snap between its openedPostion and closedPostion. 
    /// If the tray is open and the user taps anywhere within its content area, the tray will automatically close.
    /// </summary>
    AutoClosingPopup,

    /// <summary>
    /// The ActionTray can be dragged by its dragTab between the specified openedPosition and closedPosition
    /// </summary>
    Draggable,

    /// <summary>
    /// When the user taps the ActionTray's DragTab, the tray will snap between its openedPosition and closedPosition
    /// </summary>
    Popup
}

public enum ActionTrayOrientation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ActionTray is at the bottom of the screen
    /// </summary>
    Bottom,

    /// <summary>
    /// The ActionTray is on the left side of the screen
    /// </summary>
    Left,

    /// <summary>
    /// The ActionTray is on the ride side of the screen
    /// </summary>
    Right,

    /// <summary>
    /// The ActionTray is at the top of the screen
    /// </summary>
    Top
}
```

In your .iOS project, you'll need:

```
 using System.Drawing;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using **YourXamarinFormsPCLProjectReference**;
 using **YourXamarinFormsPCLProjectReference**.iOS;
 using UIKit;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using CoreGraphics;
 using Appracatappra.ActionComponents.ActionTray;

 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ActionTrayView), typeof(ActionTrayRendereriOS))]
 namespace **YourXamarinFormsPCLProjectReference**.iOS
 {
  public class ActionTrayRendereriOS : ViewRenderer<ActionTrayView, UIActionTray> 
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<ActionTrayView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.OldElement == null) 
        {
            SetNativeControl(new UIActionTray());

            Control.trayType = GetTrayType(e.NewElement.TrayType);
            Control.orientation = GetTrayOrientation(e.NewElement.Orientation);
        }
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        Control.CloseTray(false);
    }

    private UIActionTrayType GetTrayType(ActionTrayType trayType)
    {
        switch(trayType) 
        {
            case ActionTrayType.AutoClosingPopup:
            {
                return UIActionTrayType.AutoClosingPopup;
            }
            case ActionTrayType.Draggable:
            {
                return UIActionTrayType.Draggable;
            }
            case ActionTrayType.Popup:
            {
                return UIActionTrayType.Popup;
            }
            default:
            {
                return UIActionTrayType.Draggable;
            }
        }
    }

    private UIActionTrayOrientation GetTrayOrientation(ActionTrayOrientation orientation)
    {
        switch (orientation) 
        {
            case ActionTrayOrientation.Bottom:
            {
                return UIActionTrayOrientation.Bottom;
            }
            case ActionTrayOrientation.Left:
            {
                return UIActionTrayOrientation.Left;
            }
            case ActionTrayOrientation.Right:
            {
                return UIActionTrayOrientation.Right;
            }
            case ActionTrayOrientation.Top: 
            {
                return UIActionTrayOrientation.Top;
            }
            default:
            {
                return UIActionTrayOrientation.Bottom;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just insert your project name wherever it says YourXamarinFormsPCLProjectReference and you should be good to go, either in C# directly or xaml (I did it through xaml and the MVVM pattern).  There are a lot of other properties that come with the ActionTab.  If you want to be able to bind to a new property of the ActionTab, the formula is to:

1. Create a new, corresponding property in your Xamarin.Forms project.
2. Add this as a BindableProperty to the ActionTrayView class in the Xamarin.Forms project
3. Tell the custom renderer (ActionTrayRendereriOS in this example) how to handle the property.  You can handle runtime updates by overriding the OnElementPropertyChanged method in the custom renderer.  For the example above, I did not utilize OnElementPropertyChanged because the properties I gave you are set by the ActionTray when it is initialized, not sure if you can change these during the runtime after it has initially loaded (probably could, I just haven't tried that yet)

Hope that helps!